# Looking for solr query which will include results with both missing field and the same field which has number within a given range

Tags: solr, lucene

Let's say I have the following data

```
{
 fruit: "Mango",
 cost : 2.00,
 variety : "alphanso",
},
{
 fruit : "apple",
 cost : 1.40,
 variety : "Gala"
},
{
 fruit : "apple",
 variety : "cosmic crisp",
},
{
fruit : "apple",
variety : "honey crisp",
cost : 2.99
}
```

I am looking for a search that returns apples with a cost between 1 and 2 and also returns the variety that doesn't have a cost field set.

In this case, the result will contain "Gala" and "cosmic crisp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the complete set of documents, `*:*`, subtract those that have a value `[* TO *]`, and add those that match `variety:Gala`.

```
q=(*:* -cost:[* TO *]) OR variety:Gala
```